# Python 3.4.0 can't import module via script that imports successfully in interpreter

Tags: importerror, python-3.4

I'm not a newby in Python but I'm stucked with a strange issue.

I set this python project structure (excerpt):

- project-A/myapp
- project-B/core/common/lib

where *myapp / core, common & lib* are python packages.

project-B directory is set in the python path as '/root_path/to/core_module'

when I run the script that imports modules into the project-A/myapp directory :

```
from core.common.lib import Error, XmlSource, Property, Preference
```

it raises an error :

ImportError: No module named 'core'

without changing the current directory in python3 interpreter and typing in the same command :

```
jeby6372@mercure:~/factory/bubble$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr  9 2014, 20:03:10) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from core.common.lib import Error, XmlSource, Property, Preference
>>>
```

The module is loaded...  I was expecting the same behaviour as above during the script execution.

so I try added this command before the import statement that fails

```
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = '/root_path/to/core_module'
```

with no success ...

Any idea ?

Perhaps am I wrong but I assume that the python3 interpreter searches the relative import modules path  given first in the current directory and then in the defined python path wherever it's called.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you already have a look at syspath during runtime, i.e. before immporting from core.common.lib: `import sys print sys.path`

Comment: Thanks for your interest. just before the import sys.path doesn't display the awaited /root_path/to/core_module (/home/jeby6372/factory/F14). It looks that the python script was executed i na different environment. : '/opt/python-3.4.0/lib/python3.4/site-packages/lxml-3.3.4-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg', '/opt/python-3.4.0/lib/python3.4/site-packages/httpagentparser-1.6.0-py3.4.egg', '/opt/python-3.4.0/lib/python3.4/site-packages/CherryPy-...

Comment: Or perhaps that's a 3.4 new behaviour ?

Comment: You say : "project-B directory is set in the python path as '/root_path/to/core_module' " . How is it done? Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: just to avoid given real names that sometimes make misunderstandings. In fact I added /home/jeby6372/factory/F14/ to the python path : the *project-B* directory, *project-A* being /home/jeby6372/bubble/

Comment: edit : *project-A* directory = /home/jeby6372/factory/bubble/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `PYTHONPATH` inside the interpreter won't help since it' s read on interpreter startup.
The solution would be to append the path to core module to `sys.path` directly before importing it, i.e.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/core/module')
import core.module
```

I guess you forgot to export the pythonpath, try (in shell):

```
export PYTHONPATH='/path/to/core/module'
python your_python_script.py
```

Comment: Thank you. It works by placing the sys.path.append as mentioned .. But not for my prgrams that fails few lines after during a relative path file access. Using os.path.abspath('relative/path/to/core/module/file') refers to the Projetc_A/myapp/relative/path/to/core/module/file .. ;so I doesn't work in my application. I added a symlink to my core module in the myapp directory and everythng is OK now.